# VBA: Using Cell Value as DOM Element

Tags: excel, vba, dom

I would like to use a cell value in a function for grabbing a DOM element from a website.

My current code is not working because using the argument "selector" with an HTMLDocument throws an error.

```
Function HttpRequest(url,selector)

Dim http As Object, html As New HTMLDocument
Dim result As String

Set http = Create.Object("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

http.Open "GET", url, False

http.send

html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText

result = html.selector

MsgBox result

End Function
```

With the selector being "getElementsByTagName("a")(1).innerText".

I also tried to use Application.Evaluate(selector) but that is not accepted as an object.

Comment: That won't work as a generic approach without a lot more code to parse out your "selector"...  You could maybe make some headway by converting that selector to js and using the `execScript` (if that works outside of a browser...)

Comment: ExecScript doesn't seem to work with XML. I opted to parse out the selector. I also tried CallByName but couldn't get it to work. Thanks anyway!